# Makefile: split input files for command options

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

My current project contains a makefile which has, among its rules (simplified without dependencies):

```
SOURCES : = "file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt" # and so on

assembled.txt:
    myprog -I $(SOURCES)
```

THe issue is that `myprog` doesn't want a single value, but instead, it would expect:

```
myprog -I file1.txt -I file2.txt ...
```

How can I handle this in a Makefile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
SOURCES := file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

SOURCES := $(addprefix -I , $(SOURCES))

assembled.txt:
    myprog -I $(SOURCES)
```

Slightly more elegant:

```
SOURCES := file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

assembled.txt:
    myprog $(foreach S, $(SOURCES),-I $(S))
```

Answer (score 1):

@Beta,

Your first example (using addprefix) was a little off.  Should've looked like

```
SOURCES := file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt

assembled.txt:
    myprog $(addprefix -I , $(SOURCES))
```

which I think reads a little nicer than your foreach version.